# How to send the request to WebService running on multiple ports

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, configuration

I have configured my server.xml such that tomcat is running on multiple ports. I have deployed a war file and copied into all the webapps. I'm trying to send a request from separate web app to these services randomly and service inserts a record into database.

How can I modify, such that one of the available service picks up the request to insert into database rather than me randomly sending to a service running on specific port.

Let me know if I'm unclear with anything as I am still getting used to stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you check all your ports is working ? I have test my webservices using postman.. there you should specify the `port number` too.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve is called as **Load Balancing** where the available server out of multiple servers processes the request. Please refer [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/balancer-howto.html) for tomcat load balancing.